# create json object from html table using selected colums using jquery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

i was wondering how to parse html table to get json object that i can send via $.post with jquery.

i have a table

```
<table id="Report">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Kod</th>
   <th>Nazwa</th>
   <th>Ilość</th>
   <th>Netto / 1szt.</th>
   <th>Suma brutto</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>00171 </td>
  <td>SŁUP 50/1800 POŚREDNI(P) </td>
  <td>5</td><td>97.00 PLN </td>
  <td>394.31 PLN </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>00172</td>
  <td>SŁUP 50/1800 NAROŻNY(P)</td>
  <td>1</td><td>97.00 PLN</td>
  <td>78.86 PLN</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>00173 </td>
  <td>SŁUP 50/1800 KOŃCOWY(P) </td>
  <td>1</td><td>97.00 PLN </td>
  <td>78.86 PLN</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="font-weight: bold;">    
 <tr>
  <th colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">Razem netto: 1955.85 PLN</th>
  <th colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">Razem brutto: 2405.69 PLN</th>
 </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

and what i need is json object in this format (first `<td>` and third `<td>`):

```
[{"00171":5},
 {"00172":1},
 {"00173":1}
]
```

and that i can send it via

```
$.post(  
 "print.php",  
 {json: myjsonvar},  
 "json"  
);
```

any idea how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var json = [];
$('#Report').find('tbody tr').each(function(){
    var obj = {},
        $td = $(this).find('td'),
        key = $td.eq(0).text(),
        val = parseInt( $td.eq(2).text(), 10 );
    obj[key] = val;
    json.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: thanks, i didnt know that it was so easy. many solutions are really similiar but your anser gives also `val` as an integer. thanks again

Comment: `obj.key` is more preferable than `obj[key]`

Comment: `key` is not the name of a property, it is a *variable* whose *value* is the name of a property. So if you try to use `obj.key` you get the value of a property on `obj` named `key`, which will be `undefined`. Instead, you need to use `obj[ key ]`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var myjsonvar=[];

$('#Report tbody tr').each(function(){
   var data={};
   var tr=$(this);
   data[tr.find('td:first-child').text()]=tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
   myjsonvar.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why json, if you are in js already? Just create a simple object:

```
var data = {};

$("#Report tbody tr").each(function() {
   data[$(this).children("td:eq(0)").text()] = $(this).children("td:eq(2)").text();
});

$.post("print.php", data);
```

Setting type to json in `$.post` defines the server response to be `json`, not the send data!

http://jsfiddle.net/zyCPN/

Comment: thanks for you reply. i asked for json object because in my php code i had already some part for parsing json objects, so it would be a little easier for me.

Comment: @gerpaik, `json_decode()` would do that in php, however if you submit it like above you'll have `$_POST` being `array("00171" => "5", "00172" => "1", "00173" => "1");`, without any parsing necessary.

Comment: thanks for tips. really helpful. i need to check if now i can simplify my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sendData = [];

$('#Report tbody tr').each(function(i, el){
    var key = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()),
        val = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()),
        obj = {};
    obj[key] = val;
    sendData.push(obj);
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/csG5T/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var objArray=[];
$('table#Report tbody tr').each(function(i){
    var row=$(this);
    obj={};
    obj[$('td', row).eq(0).text()]=$('td', row).eq(2).text();
    objArray.push(obj);
});
```