# sending html data to view and then sending to controller to update sql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-ajax

I have a HTML table where one of the columns value is dynamically added. I have an update button, upon clicking it I want this data to get updated in my sql database. For this, I am planning to first fetch the table data and put into view , then send data to controller and then updating sql.

I am stuck at the first step,
Descibing table below

```
              <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th >Name</th>
                  <th>Active</th>
                  <th>Order By</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                  @if (ViewBag.data != null)
                                  {
                                      foreach (var item in ViewBag.data)
                                      {
                                          <tr>
                                              <td >@item.AutoID</td>
                                              <td @item.Text</td>
                                              <td >@item.Active</td>
                                              <td>@item.OrderBy</td>

                                          </tr>

                                      }

                                  }




                              </tbody>

                          </table>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Update Preference" class="BtnUpdOrderId" />

              </div>
```

I tried this below js function to fetch the data

```
 $(".BtnUpdOrderId").click(function () {
        
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var id = tr.find('input[name="autoid"]').val();
        var text = tr.find('input[name="text"]').val();
        var active = tr.find('input[name="active"]').val();
        var orderby = tr.find('input[name="orderby"]').val();
        alert('type1 : ' + id + ' ' + text + ' ' + active + ' ' + active);

    });
```

but not sure why nothing came in alert

```
var TableData = new Array();
    $('#tblLookup1 tr').each(function (row, tr) {
        TableData = TableData + $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        alert(TableData);
    });
```

then tried the above block of code to get data in a variable but still not able to get anything.

Once I get the data I can try sending from view->controller.

So need the following help:

1. what mistake am I making?
2. once this is fixed, how to send data to sql? (this is a ado.net based mvc project)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider creating a json object:
[Creating json object in mvc and returning from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438209/creating-json-object-in-mvc-and-returning-from-controller)

then build your table  [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery)

finally, the update need only post back the json object

https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2013/02/27/posting-json-data-to-an-mvc-controller-via-ajax/

if you going to use this jason object make sure you use serialization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

your have to patch these concepts together but there are a lots of tutorials and examples online so it be a good learning experience

I hope this helps

helpful links:
https://www.sqlshack.com/modifying-json-data-using-json_modify-in-sql-server/
[Updating a JSON object using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702474/updating-a-json-object-using-javascript)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-data-to-a-html-table-using-javascript-jquery/
[create json object from html table using selected colums using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043221/create-json-object-from-html-table-using-selected-colums-using-jquery)